# Reading integer to a text file in C (integer is present in a structure)

Tags: c, file

I have declared a structure that has both integer and string type variables. I am able to scan the data and print it without issues. But when I try to write the structure to the file it only reads the strings and I don't understand why.

Here's the structure:

```
struct employee_details
{
    char name[45];
    int id;
    char designation[30];
    long long int phone_number;
    char address[75];
}employee;
```

Here's the function used to get structure input:

```
void get_employee_details()
{
    printf("\nName: ");
    scanf("%s", employee.name);
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &employee.id);
    printf("Designation: ");
    scanf("%s", employee.designation);
    printf("Phone Number: ");
    scanf("%lld", &employee.phone_number);
    printf("Address: ");
    scanf("%s", employee.address);
}
```

Here's the function to write this data in the file:

```
void add_employee(int is_first_record, int to_append)
{
    FILE* p_wfile;
    if (to_append == 0)
    {
        if (is_first_record == 1)
            p_wfile = fopen("Record.txt", "w");
        else
            p_wfile = fopen("Record.txt", "a");
    }
    else
        p_wfile = fopen("Record.txt", "a");

    if (p_wfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't open file.");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nADD EMPLOYEE's DETAILS\n");

    get_employee_details();

    fwrite(&employee, sizeof(struct employee_details), 1, p_wfile);

    if (fwrite == 0)
        printf("Error writing to file!\n");

    fclose(p_wfile);
}
```

I have a loop in main() to repeat the writing process until the user wants to but no matter how many structures I input, only the characters get written.
What should I do? Is it somehow related to me using `scanf()` instead of the better functions?

Comment: How are you reading the file to see what is written? The non-string variables are probably written, but you cannot read them in notepad or similar programs. Try to read using a hexdump of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to read the file using a text editor.

**Issue is with fwrite:**
"fwrite" will write the numbers without converting it to ASCII or utf-8 chars  hence numbers won't be found when opened via file editor. Instead, you will find a characters equivalent of the numbers stored. Try reading the file using "fread" you will get the actual values back into the "employee_details" structure.

**Incase you want to read the data via file editor:** use fprint

Try something Like:
**fprintf(p_wfile , "%s %d\n", employee.name, employee.id);**